# Are there contemporary English authors that write in non-experimental ways?

Tags: identification-request, translation, literary-device, v-s-naipaul

English is not my mother tongue and in many ways, I am trying to learn and appreciate it using reading. **I have read A House for Mr Biswas by V.S. Naipaul and was amazed at the syntactical beauty of the prose. There were lines written with proper syntax and grammar and it made me learn a lot of things.**

However, my issue is that most of the other contemporary literature that I read by other authors does not offer me such joy. They are good but for a learner like me, it is too much to jump directly into experimentative literary style (or to deal with stream of consciousness writings). I want good contemporary literature that can teach me grammar and its intricacies, and that can show me the beauty of syntax in English.

Is there any contemporary author who offers such learnings? I believe one of them is John Updike and Rabbit, Run is one such novel, but are there other writers like that?

PS: I have read translated books like Red Sorghum by Mo Yan and Master and The Master and Margarita, and both of them were very well translated. But I want untranslated contemporary English texts that have more traditionally written sentences.

Comment: While [recommendation questions are off-topic](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/11259), you may ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/the-reading-room)

Comment: Try any of Ian McEwan's books.

Comment: There are many, many of them. But if you look in lists people have made of literary books, you're not likely to find that many of them, because the people who write lists of literary books are often enamored of experimental fiction (even though there are many less-experimental books that have just as much literary merit).